# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { 5 CLOSED

Tags: javascript

I am creating a simple roll a pair of dice and tracking the statistics until doubles are rolled. However, I am keep getting "SyntaxError: Unexpected token {".

Could anyone give me a word of advise on this? Thank you!

```
    //Statistics to Doubles 
    function die(){
        var rollCount=0, sum=0;
        var min=7, max=0, avg;
        var result;
        var roll1, roll2;

        do {
            rollCount++;

            roll1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6)+1);
            roll2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6)+1);

            if (roll1<min){
                min=roll1;
            }
            if (roll2<min){
                min=roll2;
            }
            if(roll1>max){
                max=roll1;
            }
            if(roll2>max){
                max=roll2;
            }
            sum+=(roll1+roll2);

        } while(roll1!=roll2);

        avg=sum/rollCount;
        result = ["rolls: "+rollCount, "min: "+min, "max: "+max, "average: "+avg];
        return result;
    }
       console.log(die());
```

UPDATE: Okay so this code seems to work very smoothly using google console in inspect element after I put them in html file.

die();
["rolls: 2", "min: 4", "max: 6", "average: 10.5"]

die();
["rolls: 4", "min: 1", "max: 6", "average: 9"]

die();
["rolls: 3", "min: 2", "max: 6", "average: 8.333333333333334"]

die();
["rolls: 27", "min: 1", "max: 6", "average: 6.62962962962963"]

die();
["rolls: 17", "min: 1", "max: 6", "average: 7.411764705882353"]

It just seems to be catching the Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { 5  at jsbin.com.
If anyone is interested: http://jsbin.com/yuzoyonoce/edit?js,console

Anyways, thank you guys for your support! CASE CLOSED

Comment: There is no error in this JavaScript. What line does that refer to?

Comment: why do you have `result` in an array.. that seems very odd to me

Comment: I am using jsbin.com to run it. and This is what is keep showing:"error"
"SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at https://static.jsbin.com/js/prod/runner-3.35.12.min.js:1:13891
    at https://static.jsbin.com/js/prod/runner-3.35.12.min.js:1:10820"

Comment: What's the 5 in your question's title?

Comment: Oh 5 means nothing. It was to avoid duplicate titles. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: can you share a fiddle link

Comment: Nothing wrong in javascript, may be problem in some other js

Comment: http://jsbin.com/yuzoyonoce/edit?js,console

okay so this code works when I run with html file inside of a script tag, but jsbin.com, it won't...interesting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsbin.com/yegeyotuyi/edit?html,js,console

The error went away while fixing spacing and indentation. Turns out it throws an exception as soon as you enter a soft return (shift-enter)

Comment: Thank you very much! Very interesting though...I usually work my code in Sublime 3 then just copy+paste to the jsbin.com to run it...Maybe I should just work directly in jsbin.com from now on.